# Get input value in child table on change select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem to get the value from input which located in child table row. Let me explain in code

```html
<table class="order-list-bank-detail"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="dom_bankselestion">
            <option value="">-- please select --</option>
            <option value="A">Bank A</option>
            <option value="B">Bank B</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <table class="order-list-bank-statement">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="dom_analysismonthyear" type="text"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

above is the sample code. What i want to achieve is, onchange **select**, alert the value of **input .dom_analysismonthyear**

Seriously I have no idea to do that in jquery/javascript. Please help me. and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$('.dom_bankselestion').change(function(ev){
  alert($('input.dom_analysismonthyear').val())
})
```

Comment: Why use jQuery to get a property from the underlying Element object? `val()` works fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point, that's fixed

Comment: You needed to remove the `[0]` too otherwise you'd get an error. I edited it for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is this:

```
el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler);
```

- is your desired event: `'change'`
- `eventHandler` is the task that should be done: i.e. a function which executes the desired `alert()`

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand, but maybe you want this:

```
$('.dom_bankselestion').on('change', function() {
  alert($('.dom_analysismonthyear').get(0).value)
  // or you can do the same result with only jQuery functions as well:
  // $('.dom_analysismonthyear').eq().val()
});
```

Comment: Why use jQuery to get a property from the underlying Element object? `val()` works fine.

Comment: Good question, let me figure out, why I use it this way:
Class selector selects all the elements with `.dom_analysismonthyear`. If you log this: `$('.dom_analysismonthyear')`, you get an Array like jQuery object, with 1 dom element. If you have 2 input with this class, you got 2 element. However the `.val()` function returns only the value of the first element. The `.get(0)` function explicitly shows what is happening.

Comment: In that case use `eq()`, not `get()`. However if the `.dom_bankselection` is related to the `.dom_analysismonthyear` element through the HTML structure then you should use DOM traversal, not selecting the element by index.

Comment: same result, but of course it can be used as well
(I've modified my answer)